# Unable to cast object of type System.DBNull to type System.String

Tags: c#, gridview

In my database I have 6 columns, all of them allow null values. I
want to make a simple form  with an updating feature.

Product , SNO  ,BTCH  Expiry ,QTY ,RATE and Amount.

I get an exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'

Here is my code :

```
int a = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

            try
            {

                using (AmdDataSet.Test_ibrahimDataTable table = new AmdDataSet.Test_ibrahimDataTable())
                {

                  int b = a+1;
                    using (AmdDataSetTableAdapters.Test_ibrahimTableAdapter adp = new AmdDataSetTableAdapters.Test_ibrahimTableAdapter())
                    {
                        adp.GetDataBySNO(a);
                         AmdDataSet.Test_ibrahimRow erow;
                        erow = table.NewTest_ibrahimRow();
                        lblSNO.Text = erow.SNO.ToString();
                        txtProduct.Text= erow.PRODUCTS;
                        txtExpiry.Text = erow.EXPIRYDATE.ToShortDateString();
                        txtBatchNo.Text = erow.BATCHNO.Trim().ToString();

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lbleror.Text = ex.Message;
            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
lblSNO.Text = (erow.SNO == null) ? string.Empty : erow.SNO.ToString()
```

or

```
lblSNO.Text = (erow.SNO == DBNull.Value) ? string.Empty : erow.SNO.ToString()
```

Comment: Actually the second option will work

Comment: lblSNO.Text = (erow.SNO == DBNull.Value) ? string.Empty : erow.SNO.ToString()    it is Showing Cannot be applied of Type int

Comment: What is the type of SNO column in the DB?

Comment: These didn't work for me.. I had to use the Is[PropertyName]Null() method of the dataset property.

Answer (score 2):

Before calling `ToString` method call `Convert.IsDBNull` to check if value is not null.